# How do I find out the recent SSH logins for Centos and their IP address?

Tags: centos

It seems someone logged into my dev server with root password and did a whole bunch of destruction. How do I check the recent logins and their IP address on Cent OS ?

Thanks.

Comment: it could be useful to have a look on the following links and check if you react correctly on the issue: http://serverfault.com/q/218005/118677, http://serverfault.com/a/107346/118677

Answer (score 29):

`lastlog(8)` will report the most recent information from the `/var/log/lastlog` facility, if you have `pam_lastlog(8)` configured.

`aulastlog(8)` will make a similar report, but from the audit logs in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. (Recommended, as `auditd(8)` records are harder to tamper with than `syslog(3)` records.)

`ausearch -c sshd` will search your audit logs for reports from the `sshd` process.

`last(8)` will search through `/var/log/wtmp` for the most recent logins. `lastb(8)` will show `bad login attempts`.

`/root/.bash_history` might contain some details, assuming the goober who fiddled with your system was incompetent enough to not remove it before logging out.

Make sure you check `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files for *all users* on the system, check `crontab`s to make sure no new ports are scheduled to be opened at some point in the future, etc. While **you really should just rebuild the machine from scratch**, it wouldn't hurt to take the time to learn what the attacker did.

Note that all logs stored on the local machine are suspect; the only logs you can realistically *trust* are forwarded to another machine that wasn't compromised. Perhaps it would be worth investigating centralized log handling via `rsyslog(8)` or `auditd(8)` remote machine handling.

Answer (score 10):

Use:

`last | grep [username]`

or

```
last | head
```

Answer (score 7):

```
grep sshd /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Answer (score 1):

see `/var/log/secure` will log like

```
pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Failed password for invalid user XXX from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```